Can a hierarchical facet structure be created using three taxonomies related via entity reference fields?
I'm working with drupal 9.5.x
I have three taxonomies: Grandparent, Parent, and Child. The Child taxonomy has an entity reference field pointing to the Parent taxonomy, and the Parent taxonomy has an entity reference field pointing to the Grandparent taxonomy.
In the Processors tab of the search index, I have selected the following options:

Using Dependent facets, I can display Parent elements when a Grandparent is selected, and when a Parent is selected, the Child elements are displayed.
What I am trying to achieve is to create a structure that behaves like a hierarchical taxonomy, where the facets would show the relationships as a hierarchy.
I have tried the Facets Taxonomy Multilevel module, but I am encountering an error that I am currently investigating.
Is there a way to achieve this hierarchical facet behavior with Search API and Solr and three taxonomies related by an entity reference field?

It feels unlikely that there would be 2 different modules/solutions out there for the same very niche requirement. You should probably persevere with the module you mentioned, and report errors to their issue queue
